How to read Apple Watch digital crown value under ScrollView
I have a ScrollView, which simply is a list. The Apple Watch's digital crown can move the list of items up and down.
But I want to read the digital crown's value, which is supposedly the binding parameter inside the .digitalCrownRotation() modifier. But it seems the crown value does not change at all as shown in this simplified example below, where the print function is never called, neither the item text in the list will display any number other than 0.0.
How to read the crown value under ScrollView?
import SwiftUI

struct sp_16_crownScrollQuestion: View {
    @State private var scrollOffset: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0..<20, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("Item \(index)_\(scrollOffset)")
                }
            }
        }
        .focusable()
        .digitalCrownRotation($scrollOffset)
        .onChange(of: scrollOffset){
            print("crown: \(scrollOffset)")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    sp_16_crownScrollQuestion()
}

